# Assuming Development on a Ruby On Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku

I wanted to get a bit of advice from the StackOverflow community on best practices/guidelines when inheriting a Rails app from another developer.

I am currently in the process of assuming control of development at my place of work. I have decent experience in front-end, SQL/Mongo, and Node.js, and a good amount of knowledge of Ruby. However, I do not have very much experience with Rails, per se.

The previous developer is being fairly unhelpful in providing dependencies and software versions of the various packages in use by the app. However, I have been able to get the following information and I have installed these dependencies (although they may differ from the versions needed by the app):

- Postgres
- Heroku CLI
- AWS CLI
- Redis
- Sidekiq
- AngularJS

Would any of you guys be able to briefly delineate the next steps of getting a previously existing app running (or point me to another source)?

Any help you all can provide is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have acces to the production system? You can derive versions from that? Do you have a backup  of the production db?

Comment: I do have a dump file from the production db. I have attempted pg_restore on it, only to encounter role and database errors.

Answer (score 1):

Things you need to retain:

1. Access credentials to all production servers and used services (including domain name and backup servers if there are any). It is not obligatory to be you, but someone at the company should have them (there may be some security/privacy related issues).
2. Access to source code
3. A fresh production backup (if possible)

Most of versions can be inferred from production system once you have full access.
Some others (like sidekiq etc) are in `Gemfile.lock` and `yarn.lock` files.

Then try to bring the system up from the backup - if you succeed - you'll be sure that everything is ok

Comment: I do actually have the source code, but not credentials to any production services/servers. I will consult the Gemfile.lock and yarn.lock files, are there any other locations in a Rails app that would be helpful to look in? Thanks!

Comment: For the credentials I think you or someone at your company will need to get like the application.yml file or something from previous dev. That should have a lot of the credentials/api keys, etc.

Comment: The credentials could also be set directly in ENV vars on the production environment. Especially if its an app that predates encrypted secrets and the developers where smart enough to not check it into source control.